# Is it possible to clear list without setting up elements to zero, to false or to null for value types?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I've decompiled mscorlib library with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and noticed that `List.Clear` method uses `Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size)` internally.

```cs
// System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
/// <summary>Removes all elements from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1" />.</summary>
public void Clear()
{
    if (this._size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size);
        this._size = 0;
    }
    this._version++;
}
```

Next, this `Array.Clear` method is setting up all array elements to zero, to false or to null, how it's described. Also `List.RemoveRange` is using `Array.Clear` method too.

```cs
// System.Array
/// <summary>Sets a range of elements in the <see cref="T:System.Array" /> to zero, to false, or to null, depending on the element type.</summary>
/// <param name="array">The <see cref="T:System.Array" /> whose elements need to be cleared.</param>
/// <param name="index">The starting index of the range of elements to clear.</param>
/// <param name="length">The number of elements to clear.</param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">
/// <paramref name="array" /> is null.</exception>
/// <exception cref="T:System.IndexOutOfRangeException">
/// <paramref name="index" /> is less than the lower bound of <paramref name="array" />.-or-<paramref name="length" /> is less than zero.-or-The sum of <paramref name="index" /> and <paramref name="length" /> is greater than the size of the <see cref="T:System.Array" />.</exception>
/// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success), SecuritySafeCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern void Clear(Array array, int index, int length);
```

Is it possible to ignore `Array.Clear(this._items, 0, this._size)` method invoking in the first code listing for value types? I think it is not necessary. Am I right?

This question is actual not only for List, but for other generic collections too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector doesn't know that elements beyond `_size` are logically unreachable.  All it sees is an array full of handles to objects, so it has to keep every one of those objects alive.  For this reason, actually setting all the handles to `null` is a necessary part of clearing the container, to allow the garbage collector to clean up the objects just removed from the list (if no other part of the program has a handle to them).

For primitive types (`List<int>`), this wouldn't be necessary, but .NET doesn't allow specializing generic types.  Value types can contain handles, so the optimization wouldn't be possible for them either, even if .NET had specialization.

Answer (score 0):

For arrays no. For lists you can.

Remember that array preallocate memory so you need to set those elements to something by default (in the case of numbers, well, it's 0).

Now, in the case of lists remember that you a have a header pointer to the first element of the list and what you can do is to just point list header to null and, if necessary, set the length variable to 0, that way your list will be empty (clear) without touching all the elements. Now this is on an [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) linked list.

On .NET CLR List it's clear by implementation that Clear operation is O(N) and that will require to traverse the [list to release references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx), why is this? I think that java [specification](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) (although this is .NET) can give you an idea of why:

> Clearing all of the links between nodes is "unnecessary", but:
>   - helps a generational GC if the discarded nodes inhabit   more than one generation
>   - is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator

Comment: @Blam since it's an ADT could be something like List.Head. I see your point, please see my edit.

Comment: This question seems to be about `List`, not `LinkedList`.  Good points concerning linked lists, however.

Comment: List does not have a Head property (that I could find).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7f69ad7.aspx